# Is there a way of accessing an Active Record attribute with a symbol?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have an ActiveRecord class - lets call it comments - which has an author attribute.

In my code at one point I have passed an instance of comments and the symbol :author to a helper method. I now find myself wanting to access the author attribute and was wondering if there's a way of doing this with what I have.

I can use `comment.read_attribute :author` but I can't use comment.write_attribute :author as it is a private method.

I suspect I'm missing something quite obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: I think I don't quite understand your problem. Would `comment.author` help you?

Comment: It would but I want to be able to pass any symbol e.g. :date, :text to the helper method and have that attribute accessed. I guess I could use eval("comment." + attr.to_s) but that seems weak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `instance_eval`

```
irb(main):006:0> class MyClass
irb(main):007:1> attr_accesor :length
irb(main):008:1> end
irb(main):012:0> c = MyClass.new
=> #<MyClass:0x27d6458>
irb(main):016:0> b = 11
=> 11
irb(main):019:0> c.instance_eval( "self.length = #{b}" )
=> 11
irb(main):020:0> c.length
=> 11
irb(main):019:0> c.instance_eval( "self.length" )
=> 11
```

or

```
irb(main):021:0> c.send :length
=> 11
```

Comment: `send` doesn't care if the method is public or private so use it carefully